# How can I change font color?

Tags: 11.10, themes, fonts

The default font color in the Ambiance theme is gray and the contrast makes it hard to read.  How can I keep the theme but make the font dark?  I knew how to do this prior to Ubuntu 11.10 but now I can't find it.  Thank you.

Comment: Same problem here. Fancy desktop themes set the font color, but do not give a suggested wallpaper, which usually ends up with a dark font on a dark wallpaper.

Comment: Which font color are we talking about? Which program?

Answer (score 5):

To change the system font color of the Ambiance theme from gray to black, you can edit these three files:

```
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
```

In these files change

`text_color:#3C3C3C`     to   `text_color:#000000`

`fg_color:#4c4c4c`        to   `fg_color:#000000`

This should greatly improve contrast and make applications' menu and dialog text much easier to read.